# The composition of functions and inverse of a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm a bit confused on how to do some of my discrete math work. I tried doing all of the problems, but I feel like I'm doing something wrong. If anyone could correct me, it would be greatly appreciated.

Suppose $g: A\rightarrow B$ and $f: B\rightarrow C$ where

$A = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, $B = \{a,b,c\}$, $C = \{2,8,10\}$, 
and $g$ and $f$ are defined by
$g = \{(1, b), (2, a), (3, b), (4, a)\}$ and
$f = \{(a,8),(b,10),(c,2)\}$

Find the following.

1) $f\circ g$

2) $f^{-1}$

3) $f\circ f^{-1}$

For one, I remember $f\circ g$ being the same as $f(g)$, so I substituted g in for every letter value in f.

$\{(\{(1,b),(2,a),(3,b),(4,a)\},8),({(1,b),(2,a),(3,b),(4,a)},10),(\{(1,b),(2,a),(3,b),(4,a)\},2)\}$

However, I'm certain I'm doing something wrong, as that's a massive jumble of values, but I'm not sure what exactly I've done wrong, or how to fix it.

As for the inverse of f, I believe it would be $\{(8,a),(10,b),(2,c)\}$

Once I learn how to properly do part one, I should be able to find $f\circ g^{-1}$ without any problem.

Comment: [Please read this.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117)

Comment: Given two binary relations $R$ and $S$, by definition one has $R\circ S:=\{(r,s)\colon \exists t((s,t)\in S\land (t,r)\in R)\}$. Use the definition to find $f\circ g$.

Comment: [This is also worth reading](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A function $g:A\rightarrow B$ is (quite often, but not always) interpreted as a subset of the cartesian product $A\times B$ having the special property that for every $u\in A$ there is exacly one element $v\in B$ with $(u,v)\in g$. Another notation for $(u,v)\in g$ is the wellknown expression $v=g(u)$. Note that from this point of view we have: $g=\{(u,g(u)\mid u\in A\}$. Also it is said that in this context '$g$ sends element $u\in A$ to element $g(u)\in B$'.
- The composition $f\circ g$ sends element $u\in A$ to element $f(g(a))\in C$, so that $f\circ g=\{(u,f(g(u))\mid u\in A\}$.
- To write $f\circ g$ as subset of $A\times C$ take element $1\in U$, note that $g$ sends it to $g(1)=b$  and then note that $f$ sends $g(1)=b$ to $f(g(1))=f(b)=10$. Do the same with the other elements to come to: $$f\circ g=\{(1,10),(2,8),(3,10),(4,8)\}$$
- You are correct where it concerns $f^{-1}$.
- Not  every function has an inverse *as function*. If you do for $g$ what you did for $f$ then you would come to $g^{-1}=\{(b,1),(a,2),(b,3),(a,4)\}$. This however is not a function (it misses the special property mentioned above). You can still refer to it as the inverse of the *relation* $g$.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I got {(8,8),(10,10),(2,2)} for f o (inverse of f), did I do it correctly? I made a typo at the end of my question and said I was doing f o (inverse of g), but the question was inverse of f.

Comment: Your result for $f\circ f^{-1}$ is fine. In fact if function $f:B\rightarrow C$ has an inverse (which is the case here) then $f\circ f^{-1}$ is automatically $\{(c,c)\mid c\in C\}$.